# How to resize 2D Java game without “squeezing” it?

Tags: java, jframe

I am trying to make my second java game (2D) but i have run in a problem: The game will be in fullscreen, but how can i make it so it is scaled properly for each screen? While researching i found out that (almost) everyone is saying the same thing: render it on a Buffered image first and then render the image on the screen resolution, which i understund how to do ( BufferedImage i = new BufferedImage(width, height, 1); BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();

```
Graphics2D g2 = i.createGraphics();
if(bs == null){
    this.createBufferStrategy(3);
    return;
}

Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
//g2.draw....

g.dispose();
bs.show();
```

) but wont that make everything look squeezed or streched? P.s. if you know any way of making it scale only by keeping the starting resolution (leaving black on both sides) i would accept it

P.s.Sorry for my english.Hope i explained it good enough (if not ask me to clarify)

Answer (score 1):

Just render the image on your JFrame/JPanel using `g.drawImage(img, x, y, width, height, obs)` with this trick:

```
JPanel panel = ...; // Your target panel
Graphics g = ...; // The graphics object of this panel (argument of paintComponent)

float scale = Math.min((float) panel.getWidth() / i.getWidth(), (float) panel.getHeight() / i.getHeight());

int displayWidth = (int) (i.getWidth() * scale);
int displayHeight = (int) (i.getHeight() * scale);

g.drawImage(i, panel.getWidth()/2 - displayWidth/2, panel.getHeight()/2 - displayHeight/2, displayWidth, displayHeight, null);
```

This way you keep the aspect ratio of the `BufferedImage` but scale it to take the maximum place of the panel.

Also, if the `BufferedImage` is smaller than the panel, then you might notice some artifacts. The easiest way to fix them is to set the rendering hint INTERPOLATION to something better, like BILINEAR:

```
g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
```